# Angular httpclient CORS request returns 404 error

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, cors

I started a sample Angular application that runs on 127.0.0.1:4200 (PC A),  I started a web browser at the same computer and everything works fine.

In the application, there is a heroService.ts that calls this.http.get etc to get the data from 127.0.0.1:4200.

I then started another http server using nodejs express which provides some API services, the IP is 192.168.2.101:3000 (PC B). The api is perfectly fine because I can run it in any web browser and see the results (all in json). In nodejs express, I installed cors too and use app.use(cors()) to enable CORS support.

The following is where the problem is.

I followed heroService.ts in PC A, and created apiService.ts, and use `this.http.get("http://192.168.2.101:3000").subscribe(_=>console.log("ok"));` to call the API at PC B (PC B should already have cors enabled).

However, it seems that Angular running at browser cannot identify this address, and in browser's debug window, I can see 404 error, http://192.168.2.101:3000 cannot be found. Note that the same url http://192.168.2.101:3000 works perfectly in web browser directly.

The weird thing is that in the browser's (chrome and edge) network debug window, I could not see any request was sending out, there's no such request sent to the server. And at the nodejs's server side, I tried to log any connections and I could not see any too. It seemed to me that the web browser didn't send this http get out, and the angular library returned 404 directly.

I tried to search the same error but could not find anything useful.

I would guess that Angular's library will keep using the base url (127.0.0.1:4200) and will not parse http://192.168.2.101:3000 ? Is there a way to solve it?

I hope I explained the problem clearly.

Thanks for help.

Comment: It does find the server, otherwise you wouldn't get a 404 response from that server. 404 means that the server was found by the browser, but that the server couldn't get the resource that the browser asks. So check what happens on the server.

Comment: @JBNizet Hi, thanks. However, I use a browser to test the link, it works perfectly and I can see "Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *" in browser network response too. The weird thing is that if I use Angular's this.http.get to get this link, in the browser's (chrome and edge) network debug window, I cannot see any request was sending out, there's no such request sent to the server. And at the nodejs's server side, I tried to log any connections and I cannot see any too. It seems to me that it is web browser doesn't send this http get out, but the angular library returns 404 directly.

Comment: @user534498 you may need to use proxy configurations for this, probably this may helps you out https://angular.io/guide/build.

Comment: You may not see the network request for a cors error if the OPTIONS request failed, if so then the subsequent GET request would not be sent, this is normal when a client is accessing a service on another host (making a CORS request). To test for certain if the server/client is the issue I'd suggest using Postman to call http://192.168.2.101:3000 and see if you get the same error. It could be your route config even if your cors setting is correct

Answer (score 1):

I think you got an error something similar to this.

*Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:1337/api/Jobs/addjob' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains the invalid value ''.*

So you should **enable Cross Origin Resource Sharing( also known as CORS)**. To do that we need to set the correct headers in the response, which allow a browser to make use of the data from any domain.

To load data to client-side code(front-end) with using frameworks like Angular, from server-side(back-end) you can use middleware function in express(Node.js) before you define your routes.

`app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
  next();
});`

The below link will help to gain more knowledge about "enable CORS express.js (node.js)".
https://jonathanmh.com/how-to-enable-cors-in-express-js-node-js/